# App Store Connect: Can I find the bundle Id of my app anywhere?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm logged into App Store Connect and have two apps. If I go into one of them, is there a place where it shows the bundle ID? When I open the app in XCode I can see the bundle ID, but I'm wondering how XCode knows which app to upload to on App Store Connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to your App in App Store connect. Choose General > App Information. The bundle ID is visible on this screen (labeled appropriately).